# How can i display selected products in the checkout tabs?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, checkout

How can i display certain selected products in the checkout tabs by attribute-value?. I have some Products which have individual information for freight and i would like top display them within the fright-tab in checkout.
But just these products.

How can i manage this. I found this script:

```
                            $quote = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote();
                            foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
                                // output details of an item.
                                echo $item->getName();
```

but i displays very products from the cart. I just want to display the product which have value in this right-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could foreach through that list and check if the corresponding product has the attribute you are looking for.

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
    if ($quote->getProduct()->hasFreight()) {
        // Show this product..
    }
}
```